# Damped Forced Oscillator with initial conditions

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

The equation of motion of a damped forced oscillator is;

$$\ddot{x}(t)+\gamma\dot{x}(t)+\omega_0^2x(t)=F(t),$$

$$F(t) = F_0 \cos(\omega_dt);$$ also for the purpose of this problem we may set $\omega_d=\omega_0=\omega$, just not inside cos and sine arguments.

and 
$$x(t)=A(\omega_d)\cos(\omega_dt-\delta),$$
which is a steady-state solution. From my understanding, it is a particular solution only.

We need to find a full sol. ($x(t)=x_\text{characteristic} + x_\text{particular}$) to a damped forced oscillator with initial conditions, $x(0)=x'(0)=0$.

Here's my result;

$$(t)=\frac{F_0}{r\omega}^{−\gamma /2}\sin(\omega ) + \frac{F_0}{r\omega}\cos\left(\omega _d  + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

Now, I want to calculate the total power on the system and integrate the result for further interpretation.

I know that power = force $\times$ velocity

Power due to external/driving force:
$P = F(t) \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$

Power due to damping force: 
$P = −\gamma \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2$

But which $x(t)$ sol. do I use for $\frac{dx}{dt}$?

Comment: What's the problem? You have $x(t)$, so $P(t)=x'(t)\times F(t)$.

Comment: Yes, but do I use x(t) - the steady-state solution? Or should I use the solution I obtained through applying initial conditions?

Comment: There is only one $x(t)$ and that's the one to use. Your 4th equation.

Comment: What about the steady-state solution, i.e. the third equation? Would I use that in the absence of initial conditions to calculate the power?

Comment: If you want to know $P(t)$ at steady state only, then yes.

Comment: So I'm using my 4th equation, x(t) full solution, to calculate the power. I took the derivative of the solution to obtain (x'(t)) to use with the power formula. Now, I was told that I can ignore the sin term in my result because it is a weakly damped oscillator. Why is that?